# how add marks to directory in node js

Tags: node.js, express

this is the structure of my node app

[image]

I'm trying to import `auth.js` file to `user.js` file.

using this statement import working fine.

```
const auth = require('./../controllers/auth')
```

but I seen some of project use `app` mask to `root` directory like below.

```
const auth = require('app/controllers/auth')
```

still I cannot figure it out.

can you help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do something like that you need to use variable and you can do it like that

```
const path = require('path');
const app_root = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

And then

```
const auth = require(`${app_root}/controllers/auth`)
```

*Note that this is the reference to the folder where your main file is located